# JQuery toggle in Visual Composer

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am using the below on click code within Visual Composer. I know very little about Jquery but was given this screen support by my themes support desk.

[image]

This works fine(although I am toggling a whole row rather than an individual element) but I need the page to also scroll down to the bottom of the now visible row/div.

I have seen other questions on here which are similar which show how to do this by writing additional jQuery code.

Hopefully this can be done in the 'On Click Code' box of Visual Composer as I am not in a position to fully learn jQuery and how to use it in Wordpress at this time.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a question about the inner workings of a third party plugin/theme, you have a better chance of getting an answer at its author's forum

Comment: Thank you cjbj, they are really slow to get back, usually giving one sentence answers then having to wait another 24 to 48hrs for a response. In regards to this issue I am actually learning how to create my first script to accomplish what I am trying to do, so will answer my own question with that response when I get it to work.